# I want to change the placeholder value and styles in the table filter. Is there any way to do that?

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

in reactjs core ui data tabel i want to change placehoder of tableFilter

```
<CDataTable
  items={teachers.dataArr}
  fields={["first_name", "last_name", "email", "level", "number", "Status", "Action"]}
  hover
  tableFilter
  itemsPerPageSelect
  sorter
  pagination
  striped
  itemsPerPage={5}
  activePage={page}
/>
```